# Explicit computation of integral closure of a number field : verification

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

The final task is to show that the integral closure of $\mathbb Q[\theta]$ over $\mathbb Q$ is $\mathbb Z[\theta]$, where $\theta = \sqrt[3]3$.

I was given a list of steps, and I would like to check that I have done them right. First, denote the integral closure (which we must show is equal to $\mathbb Z[\theta]$) by $O$.

> 1 . Show that $Z[\theta] \subset O$.

If $x = a +  b \theta + c \theta^2$ then $(T- x)(T - x_1)(T-x_2) = 0$ is a monic polynomial in $T$ with integer coefficients which $x$ satisfies, where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the expression for $x$ with $\theta$ replaced by $\omega \theta$ and $\omega^2 \theta$ where $\omega^3 = 1$ is an imaginary cube root of unity.

> 2 . Use the dual basis to show that $3O \subset \mathbb Z[\theta]$.

The dual basis(under the trace) for the (ordered) standard basis $\{1,\theta,\theta^2\}$ for $\mathbb Q[\theta]$ over $\mathbb Q$ can be found to be $\{\frac 13, \frac{\theta^2}{9},\frac{\theta}{9}\}$. From here, we conclude that $\mathbf 9O \subset \mathbb Z[\theta]$.  I do not see how to get from $9$ to $3$ using just the dual basis argument alone.

> 3 . Show that $O / (\theta) \cong \frac {\mathbb Z}{3\mathbb Z}$.

To see this, we note that $O/(3) \cong (\frac{\mathbb Z}{3 \mathbb Z})^3$ (I will not elaborate here : this is a standard result I can use). Now, define the maps $O/(3) \to O/(\theta^2) \to O/(\theta)$ by $a + (3) \to a + (\theta^2) \to a + (\theta)$.

Clearly, these are well defined as $(3) \subset (\theta^2) \subset (\theta)$. Furthermore, they are surjective maps, and are not isomorphisms, since for example, $\theta^2 + (3) \to 0$ and $\theta + (\theta^2) \to 0$. (Since $\theta^{-1} \notin O$, which is easy to check, the above cosets are non-zero cosets).

Consequently, $O/(\theta)$ is isomorphic to a strict subgroup of a strict subgroup of $(\frac{\mathbb Z}{3\mathbb Z})^3$, which leaves only two options : either it is trivial, or it is equal to $\frac {\mathbb Z}{3\mathbb Z}$. But of course it cannot be trivial : $1 + (\theta) \neq 2 + (\theta)$ are two distinct cosets, for example, as $1 \notin (\theta)$. So the result follows.

> 4 . Show that $(\theta)^rO + \mathbb Z[\theta] = O$ for all $r \geq 1$.

I am slightly unsure on how to do this part. In particular, I would like to quotient out $(\theta)$ and claim that the left hand side is just $\frac{\mathbb Z[\theta]}{(\theta)}$, since the other subgroup consists of multiples of $\theta$. This quotient has exactly three elements, so the isomorphism should follow.

> 5 . Deduce the conclusion.

We have for $r = 6$, that $(\theta^6)O + \mathbb Z[\theta] = 9O + \mathbb Z[\theta] = \mathbb Z[\theta]$ by the dual basis argument, but then from 4. we are done.

---

In particular, point 4 is my only hindrance, but I have put out the entire exercise so that somebody can point out other mistakes or places to be careful if required.

Comment: $\Bbb Z[\theta]$ doesn't only consist of things of the form $a+b\theta$.

Comment: That is a mistake which I should have noticed. We must have $\mathbb Z[\theta] = a+b\theta  + c \theta^2$ in that case (minimal polynomial is of degree three), and (with a little foresight)  its conjugates(over $\mathbb C$) would be $a + b \omega \theta + c\omega^2\theta^2$ and $a + b \omega^2 \theta + c\omega \theta^2$, where $\omega$ is an imaginary cube root of $-1$. The polynomial with exactly these numbers as roots, I would expect to be monic and have integer coefficients. This should be easy to check.

Comment: You just need to point out that $\theta$ is integral, since it's a theorem that integral elements form a ring.

Comment: That is, $O$ is a ring that contains $\mathbb Z$ and $\theta$, so we are done. Yes, this also does the job, better than what I said! Thank you again.